# how to call a script in the remote machine without using ssh

Tags: shell, scripting, ssh

I have to run a shell script which is on a remote machine from the script on my local machine.

I thought of using ssh in my script but it would prompt for password which does not help as I will need to make this script run as a cronjob.

Could anyone just guide me like what would be ideal to use rather than using ssh to connect to the remote machine and run the script present there.

Comment: You can do authentication for SSH via "keys" - http://superuser.com/questions/61170/generate-authentication-key-for-ssh which can remove the need for a password. This would be appropriate for use in a cronjob.

Comment: From the perspective of the malicious attacker, it would be ideal if you did not use authentication.  You could use rsh, but the reason ssh exists is that it is a major security hole to do such things without authentication.  Use ssh with keys instead of a password.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can set up passwordless `ssh` connections using private keys (that's what I should do).

If that's not an option, well there is `expect`, and [here's an old but working tutorial](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3065).